# Send request with parameter IBM Worklight

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I've already use http adapter and successfully send a request

but I can't do it with parameter

I want to send the parameter `cmd=login`

how to put it in `parameter = []` ?

```
var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'RSSReader',
        procedure : 'login',
        parameters :[]
    };
```

----------------------update-------------------------------

I try the official parameter format

```
var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'HTTPAdapter',
        procedure : 'login',
        parameters :[{name : 'cmd', value : 'login'}]
    };
```

but still send nothing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<displayName>HTTPAdapter</displayName>
<description>HTTPAdapter</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>my-ip-address</domain>
        <port>80</port> 
        <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
        <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
        <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
        -->     
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>

<procedure name="login"/>
```

and this is the adapter impl

```
function login() {

var input = {
    method : 'post',
    returnedContentType : 'json',
    path : '/sp/api/'
};

return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);}
```

Comment: What is this variable? what is "cmd"? Is it from the HTML? Did you simply try `parameters :['cmd=login']`?

Comment: 'cmd' is the key and 'login' is the value, it's a http post request

Comment: It's still not clear enough - what is the destination of this key:value? Into a URL path? Be clearer on the scenario.

Comment: it's the parameter after url in get request

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you. Do you mean that you want to place cmd=login like so: "http://www.foobar.com/?cmd=login"?

Comment: ex: "http://example.com/?cmd=login"

Comment: sorry that i didn't express clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the examples provided in a newly creatd HTTP adapter in the -impl.js file.
You can do this like so:

**Client JavaScript**

```
var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'myAdapter',
    procedure : 'myProcedure',
    parameters :['cmd=login']
};
...
...
```

**Adapter XML**

```
...
...
<connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <domain>www.example.com</domain>
    <port>80</port> 
</connectionPolicy>
```

**Adapter JavaScript**

```
function myProcedure(myParameter) {
    path = getPath(myParameter);

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : path
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

function getPath(myParameter) {
    return ("?" + myParameter);
}
```

Comment: I found the parameter format in the official document

Comment: 05_01_Overview_of_client_technologies, i try but it still send nothing(but i actually send the request) I've edit my question

Comment: add your adapter XML and provide the FULL *EXPECTED* URL structure - edit the question with this information.

Comment: the server get the request successfully just no parameters, so i think the adapter is OK

Comment: You do not mention if you've followed the example in my answer (namely, passing the parameter and using it like in my answer).

Comment: btw I use "run as" -> "Invoke Worklight back-end service" and the parameter is sucessfully send

Comment: again, did you try to pass the parameter to the path like in my example?

Comment: thanks for help! It works! ,sorry for annoying you, i did try your answer yesterday but i may miss something so it fail

Comment: I have one more question, is jquery or other way available to send a request in Worklight ? or only adapter can do this?

Comment: jQuery is just one approach to JavaScript. So you don't mean jQuery... rather may AJAX which is a way to send requests in JavaScrip. You can use that, but you can't use AJAX to access Worklight-secured backends with all the features that are coupled with it, AJAX requests do NOT go through Worklight Server. For that you need to use Worklight Adapters.

Comment: so I still can use ajax to access third-party web api to get some data  without adapter?

Comment: Yes. Adapters are used to access enterprise backends that sit behind Worklight Server and can be protected by Worklight security fraemwork. AJAX request to other web services are not included.